# Linux terminal - jump to first line of command output message

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

After trying to compile my program on Linux, I occasionally get error messages. Sometimes I get a lot needing me to scroll all the way to the top to see where my code broke first. Is there a short cut/faster method to scroll to the first output after I run for example a command like "make file"

I have tried "make file | less", but this chops off the first half of all the error messages, which is the part I am interested in, given that the error messages in the latter half is a result of something not being compiled correctly in the beginning of my file.

Comment: The error messages are written to stderr.  Try `make 2>&1 | less`

Comment: Or, try something like: `m() { make "$@" 2>&1 | "${PAGER-less}"; }`